# Extract file name after '>' from command line in python

Tags: python, command-line

How can I extract the filename after sign '>' from a command line in python. For example:

python func.py -f file1.txt -c > output.txt

I want to get the output file name 'output.txt' from the above command line.

Thanks

Comment: How are you getting the command line? Is it a string? Is somebody inserting it?

Comment: That information is not available to Python.

Comment: Python never sees that part of the command line; the shell interprets it as an output redirection.  All you have to do in your code is ordinary `print()`s, or `sys.stdout.write()`, and it will automatically go to the specified file.

Comment: If you want to be able to switch between stdout and output to text file, you could look at redirecting from Python instead of using >  https://dzone.com/articles/python-101-redirecting-stdout

Comment: My problem is not how to redirect the output to a file. I know it would automatically write the output to the specified file using sys.stdout. The problem is just to get the file name after '>' given by user

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I need to do this because I want to deal with the situation where user does not provide an argument for the output file but uses '>' instead. The output file will be read as an input for further data processing, hence I need to know the filename. There is a workaround but it would be much simpler if somehow the filename can be extracted directly from the command line

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

When you write something like `command > file` in shell, the shell:

1. creates the `file` if it doesn't exist,
2. opens it, and
3. assigns the descriptor to the stdout of `command`.

The called process (and it doesn't matter if that's Python or something else) doesn't know what happens to the data after it's written because it only sees the *descriptor* provided by the shell. It's a bit like having one end of a really long pipe: you know you can put stuff in, but you can't see what happens to it on the other end.

If you want to retrieve the file name in that call, you need to either:

- pass it to your Python program as an argument and handle redirection from Python, e.g. `python func.py -f file1.txt -c output.txt`, or
- output it from the shell, e.g. `echo 'output.txt'; python func.py -f file1.txt -c > output.txt`

Comment: The problem is that user can either type: 'python func.py -f file1.txt -c -o output.txt' or 'python func.py -f file1.txt -c > output.txt'. The first case is simple but the problem is with the second one.

Comment: @AnNguyen Yes? I addressed the second case in my answer.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense because user won't type 'echo 'output.txt''

Comment: You can wrap the call to python and the redirection into a shell script.